# The getter '_controller' was called on null. Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using this package in Flutter: https://pub.dev/packages/circular_countdown_timer

However, I need to create a separate widget to separate my code a little bit. I created something like this:

```
import 'package:circular_countdown_timer/circular_countdown_timer.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomOtpCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final String duration;
  final String accountName;
  final String otp;
  final Function(CountDownController) onComplete;

  CustomOtpCard({
    @required this.duration,
    @required this.accountName,
    @required this.otp,
    @required this.onComplete,
  });

  @override
  _CustomOtpCardState createState() => _CustomOtpCardState();
}

class _CustomOtpCardState extends State<CustomOtpCard> {
  CountDownController _controller = CountDownController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: ListTile(
        leading: CircularCountDownTimer(
          duration: int.parse(widget.duration),
          onComplete: widget.onComplete(_controller),
          initialDuration: 0,
          ringColor: Colors.grey[300],
          fillColor: Colors.purple,
          backgroundColor: Colors.purple[500],
          width: 50.0,
          height: 50.0,
        ),
        title: Text(widget.accountName),
        subtitle: Text(widget.otp),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now, I use it like this:

```
return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _totpItems.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return CustomOtpCard(
                    duration: '30',
                    onComplete: (controller) {
                      BlocProvider.of<TotpGeneratorBloc>(context)
                          .add(GetTotpItemsEvent());

                      controller.restart();
                    },
                    accountName: _totpItems[index].accountName,
                    otp: _totpItems[index].otp,
                  );
                },
              );
```

Then the error shows up "The getter '_controller' was called on null.". Here's the image of my error:
[image]

It says, that the _controller I passed to the callback is null. What am I doing wrong? Can someone give me a hint?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that when you call `controller.restart()`, `_CustomOtpCardState` has been disposed then `_controller` do not exist anymore.

You could do it this way :

First turn `onComplete` to a `VoidCallback` (equivalent to `void Function()`) :

```dart
final VoidCallback onComplete;
```

Then use it this way :

```dart
...
duration: int.parse(widget.duration),
onComplete: () {
    widget.onComplete();
    _controller.restart();
},
initialDuration: 0,
...
```

In your `ListView.builder` :

```dart
return CustomOtpCard(
   duration: '30',
   onComplete: () {
       BlocProvider.of<TotpGeneratorBloc>(context)
            .add(GetTotpItemsEvent());
   },
   accountName: _totpItems[index].accountName,
   otp: _totpItems[index].otp,
);
```

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. The onComplete callback doesn't fire the BlocProvider.

Comment: It shows me the same error: "The getter '_controller' was called on null" when I fire the BlocProvider.

Comment: Do you have any stackstrace with your error ?

Comment: Okay, I found the culprit. I forgot to add the controller parameter to CircularCountDownTimer.